# sudo -E -s does not preserve ZDOTDIR

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

Running `zsh` on macOS Ventura

→ With
`sudo --preserve-env -s` the environment variable `ZDOTDIR` is not preserved but all the others are.

→ With `sudo --preserve-env=ZDOTDIR -s` the variable `ZDOTDIR` is preserved but not the other variables.

Why is `ZDOTDIR` not preserved in the first case ?

Comment: DO you mean -E -s or the commands you have in the text?

Comment: -E is the short version of --preserve-env